# How to convert VGG16 caffemodel in model zoo from old definition "layers" to "layer"?

Tags: python, caffe

I want to add a new python layer to the VGG16 model, But is seems that Python layer [does not support old layer definition "layers"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/O2xSt0Th-qI), and I want use the pre-trained VGG16 caffemodel trained using prototxt with "layers",but it can not be used in prototxt with "layer". So is there any to convert the caffemodal, making it applicable with "layer"?

Answer (score 1):

just using the **tools/upgrate_net_proto_text** to convert "layers" to "layer", and the caffemodel can be used by both of them.